# Script to enable services one after the other, waiting for the previous one to start fully

Tags: windows, powershell, service, status

I'm trying to write code to start a list of services one after the other, the next service cannot start until the first one has had a chance to start.

```
# Define System Variables
$workingdirectory="c:\powershell\"
$currentDate = date -uformat "%d%m%y-%H%M"
$logFile = ($workingdirectory+"StartLog-$currentDate.txt")
$tslist=IMPORT-CSV($workingdirectory+"start.csv")

#Logwrite function to append to log file
Function logwrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

#Write current date to log file
logwrite ("Starting ESB Services")
$startlogdate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy - hh:mm:ss"
logwrite ($startlogdate)
logwrite ("-----------------")

#runs through each entry in the CSV file defined by $tslist
ForEach ($_.ts in $tslist)
{
    $svc=get-service $_.ts
    logwrite ("Starting service -", $_.ts)
    start-service $svc.name

    #if the 2nd column is set to true then we need to wait until it starts
    if ($_.wait -eq "true")
    {
        logwrite "waiting for",$_.ts,"to be started"

        #Waits for the service to get to status of Running or time taken to reach 5 minutes
        $svc.waitforstatus('Running','00:05:00')

        #Check that the service is running
        if ($svc.status -ne "Running")
        {   
            logwrite $_.ts, "Failed to start service within 4 Minutes"
        }
        else
        {
            logwrite $_.ts, "Service started successfully"
        }
    }
    else
    {

    #Wait 5 seconds between each service startup
    start-sleep -s 5

        #Check that the service is running
        if ($svc.status -ne "Running")
        {   
            logwrite $_.ts, "Failed to start service"
        }
        else
        {
            logwrite $_.ts, "Service started successfully"
        }
    }
logwrite "-----------------"
}
#Write end date to the log file
logwrite "Script finished"
$stoplogdate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy - hh:mm:ss"
logwrite ($stoplogdate)
```

The problem I have is that immediately on starting the service according to this code is set to **Running**, if I query the service status using another powershell script like this

```
$svc= get-service "service name"
write-host $svc.status
```

Then i'm returned a value of **Startpending**, i've tried inserting another

```
$svc=get-service $_.ts
```

immediately after the command to start the service but the service status still thinks it's at a state of **Running**.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some slight amendments, but if you could provide the headers that are included in the csv file.

```
# Define System Variables
$workingdirectory = "c:\powershell\"
$currentDate = date -uformat "%d%m%y-%H%M"
$logFile = ($workingdirectory + "StartLog-$currentDate.txt")
$tslist = IMPORT-CSV($workingdirectory + "start.csv")

#Logwrite function to append to log file
Function logwrite
{
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

#Write current date to log file
logwrite ("Starting ESB Services")
$startlogdate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy - hh:mm:ss"
logwrite ($startlogdate)
logwrite ("-----------------")

#runs through each entry in the CSV file defined by $tslist
ForEach ($ts in $tslist)
{
    $svc = get-service $ts.ts
    logwrite ("Starting service -", $ts.ts)
    start-service $svc.name

    #if the 2nd column is set to true then we need to wait until it starts
    if ($ts.wait -eq "true")
    {
        logwrite "waiting for", $ts.ts, "to be started"

        #Waits for the service to get to status of Running or time taken to reach 5 minutes
        $svc.waitforstatus('Running', '00:05:00')

        #Check that the service is running
        if ($svc.status -ne "Running")
        {
            logwrite $ts.ts, "Failed to start service within 4 Minutes"
        }
        else
        {
            logwrite $ts.ts, "Service started successfully"
        }
    }
    else
    {

        #Wait 5 seconds between each service startup
        start-sleep -s 5

        #Check that the service is running
        if ($svc.status -ne "Running")
        {
            logwrite $ts.ts, "Failed to start service"
        }
        else
        {
            logwrite $ts.ts, "Service started successfully"
        }
    }
    logwrite "-----------------"
}
#Write end date to the log file
logwrite "Script finished"
$stoplogdate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy - hh:mm:ss"
logwrite ($stoplogdate)
```

Comment: I managed to fix this by removing the wait check and refreshing the status by using the refresh() command. Thanks for looking into it:)